# Greatest Lower Bound and k

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Greatest Lower Bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294237/greatest-lower-bound)

We let $A$ be a nonempty bounded set and define $B=${$x+k|x \in A$}, where $k$ is a fixed real number.

I'm trying to show that glb$B$ = glb$A$ + $k$